# HTMLから要素を取り出す

Tags: swift, html, xcode

私はSwiftでサイトのHTMLを取得し、Stringにして出力するところまでできたのですが、そこから要素を取り出す方法がわかりません。
例えばAppleのホームページを指定したら「オールスクリーンのデザイン。iPhoneで最も長いバッテリー駆動時間。」などの要素を取得したいです。
つまりHTMLから不要な情報を削除するということです。
おそらく<>の中を削除するというようにすればいいのだと思うのですが、やり方を調べてもヒットしませんでした。
わかる方がいらっしゃったら教えてください。

追記:やはりパーサーを使うべきでしょうか

※初投稿でよくわかっていないので、やり方が違っても教えてください

Comment: パーサーでもいいですが、正規表現で取得する方法もあります。正規表現だと簡単ですが誤作動があるかもしれないのと、JSで出力された要素は取得できません。そのときは、WebViewでサイトを読み込み、WebViewに対してSwiftからJSを発行し、JSサイドで要素を検索、取得した後JSからSwiftにコールバックしてください。WebViewを使用するほうが確実であり、JSで動的に出力されたものでも何でも取得可能です。

Answer (score 1):

取得したHTMLソースから表示されるテキストを文字列として取得したいのであれば、`AttributedString`を使う方法があります。

以下は、OS X 10.14.4 & Xcode 10.2 の`playground`で動作する例です。

```
import Cocoa

let html = """
<html>
    <title>test title</title>
    <body>
        <p>This is a test</p>
        <p>This is a test two</p>
    </body>
</html>
"""

if let htmlData = html.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    do {
        if let attributedHTMLStr: NSAttributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            print(attributedHTMLStr.string)  // attributedHTMLStr.string が、取得したいテキスト要素
        }

    } catch let (error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)  //  例外が起きたとき、その例外の内容を表示するためのprint文
    }
}
```

`AttributedString`クラスのインスタンスのプレーンテキストを参照する`string`というプロパティで取得出来ますので、
今回は`NSAttributedString`のインスタンスは`attributedHTMLStr`ですので、

`let str: String = attributedHTMLStr.string`
で変数`str`に`html`ソースからタグや図を取り除いた文字列が得られます。